# arcpy.da cursor iteration not started?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

I am trying to convert cursors written in 10.0 to use the new arcpy.da module in 10.2.1. If I step through the code in debug mode, it steps into the for loop; however, when I attempt to run the code I get an exception **: iteration not started**

code for 10.0

```
for row in updateCursor:
    if row.getValue("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX") in ['N', 'S', 'W']:
        row.setValue("STREET_DIR_PREFIX",  row.getValue("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX"))
        row.setValue("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX", None)
```

code for 10.2.1

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(civicAddress, flds) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] in ['N', 'S', 'W']:
            row[1] = row[0]
            row[0] = None
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

I have quite a few code blocks as above that deal with specific logic cases.

Here is the full code for that section, maybe it will help:

```
flds = ("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX", "STREET_DIR_PREFIX", "STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX", "CIVIC_ID")
flds2 = ("CIVIC_ID", "UNIT_NUMBER")
log.information ("Creating cursors...")
insertCursor =  arcpy.da.InsertCursor(subAddress, flds2)
#row = []

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(civicAddress, flds) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] in ['N', 'S', 'W']:
            row[1] = row[0]
            row[0] = None

        if row[2] in ['N', 'S', 'W']:
            row[1] = row[2]
            row[2] = None

        if row[2] in unitLst:
            newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
            newrow[0] = row[3]
            newrow[1] = row[2]
            row[2] = None
            insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)


        if row[0] in unitLst:
            newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
            newrow[0] = row[3]
            newrow[1] = row[0]
            row[0] = None
            insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)

        try:
            if re.match("[0-9][A-Z]", row[0]) or re.match("[0-9][0-9][A-Z]", row[0]) or \
            re.match("[A-Z][0-9]", row[0]) or re.match("[A-Z][0-9][0-9]", row[0]):
                newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
                newrow[0] = row[3]
                newrow[1] = row[0]
                row.setValue("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX", None)
                row[0] = None
                insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            if re.match("[0-9][A-Z]", row[2]) or re.match("[0-9][0-9][A-Z]", row[2]) or \
            re.match("[A-Z][0-9]", row[2]) or re.match("[A-Z][0-9][0-9]", row[2]):
                newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
                newrow[0] = row[3]
                newrow[1] = row[2]
                row[2] = None
                insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            if row[0].isdigit():
                newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
                newrow[0] = row[3]
                newrow[1] =  row[0]
                row.setValue("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX", None)
                row[0] = None
                insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            #if row.getValue("STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX").isdigit():
            if row[2].isdigit():
                newrow = insertCursor.newRow()
                #newrow.setValue("CIVIC_ID", row.getValue("CIVIC_ID"))
                newrow[0] = row[3]
                # newrow.setValue("UNIT_NUMBER", row.getValue("STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX"))
                newrow[1] = row[2]
                #row.setValue("STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX", None)
                row[2] = None
                insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)
        except:
            pass

    rows.updateRow(row)
    del row
    del newrow
    del rows
```

Comment: Which line of code does it return the error on?

Comment: How did you define the variables `civicAddress` and `flds`?

Comment: I had some exception handling that was masking the location of the error, but when I remove that the line it fails on is rows.updateRow(row)which appears inline with the for loop.

Comment: civicAddress = ("{0}\{1}".format(outputGDB, "CIVIC_ADDRESS"))

Comment: flds = ("STREET_NUMBER_PREFIX", "STREET_DIR_PREFIX", "STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX", "CIVIC_ID")

Comment: Looks like the formatted path is incorrect.  Try hardcoding it and see if that fixes the problem (e.g. `r'C:\temp\test.gdb\myFC'`).

Comment: hardcoded the path, same error.

Comment: Ok but it works just fine in the 10.0 script and when I hard code the path I get the same error so I'm pretty sure that's not the reason it's failing. I appreciate the help tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do updates with your UpdateCursor, you'll need to move `rows.updateRow(row)` inside your for loop:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(civicAddress, flds) as rows:
  for row in rows:
  ...snip...
    rows.updateRow(row) #needs to be indented inside loop

  del row
  del newrow
  del rows
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, it was the incorrect indentation of rows.updateRow(row) that was not allowing iteration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I bet the issue stems from mixing `UpdateCursors` with `InsertCursors`. Instead of having both processing simultaneously, I suggest separating the two.

Create an empty list prior to either.

```
li = []
```

Remove your `InsertCursor` from the start of the script, and any `newrow = insertCursor.newRow()` should also be removed. Then, replace all your `insertCursor.insertRow(newrow)` with `li.append ((row[x], row[y]))`, where x and y are the appropriate indexes.

Finally, once your `UpdateCursor` is complete, perform your `InsertCursor` with rows from your list.

```
insertCursor =  arcpy.da.InsertCursor(subAddress, flds2)
for rw in li:
    insertCursor.insertRow(rw)
```

Comment: This is good advice. And if the target of both cursors is the same data source, you'll need to be in an editing session. [see first note here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/)

Comment: Thanks. I think your simple answer is correct however!